# How I can use class-based view in ViewSet?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a ViewSet:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

And appropriate urls:

```
from .users.api.views import UserViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('users', UserViewSet, 'user')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^v1/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

It works, but I want to add username-password authentification to UserViewSet:

```
@list_route(methods=['post'], permission_classes=[AllowAny])
def login(self, request):
    #check login and password
    #creare and return token
```

Of cource I can write It by my-self, but I interest, how I can use `rest_framework.authtoken.views.ObtainAuthToken` for my goals.

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation, you can expose an API endpoint that takes a username/password and returns a token using `rest_framework.authtoken.view.obtain_auth_token`. See the [rest framework Docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#by-exposing-an-api-endpoint) for more details. You urls.py would look like this:

```
from .users.api.views import UserViewSet
from rest_framework.authtoken import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('users', UserViewSet, 'user')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^v1/', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^v1/login, views.obtain_auth_token)
]
```

If you really want this url to belong to the `UserViewSet` that you've already defined, you will need to define a `detail_route` and manually call `authenticate` and then generate a token for the authenticated user (if authenticate succeeds). I recommend using the first pattern I described as it's less code/customization.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'have already done how you recommend. I just thought that it's possible to collect class-based views in ViewSet.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "class-based views in ViewSet". I mentioned in the answer that you can try defining your own custom detail route that may do what you are talking about. But this is a lot of extra code that doesn't really seem necessary. What is your motivation for doing it that way?